# How to scale up the slider in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming

When you put for example `Button` inside `DockPanel`, the button boundaries will be stretched, but the text inside the button will not be scaled.

So I use `ViewBox` as an easy way to scale -- this way (for example) button boundaries are scaled up and also the text itself.

Unfortunately `Slider` when put inside `DockPanel` behaves similar to button -- its boundaries are stretched, but the ruler and the knob remains small. When I put it inside `ViewBox` the knob is scaled correctly, however the ruler is not scaled up, but the opposite -- it is minimized.

So how to correctly scale up the slider?

*I have a window with few controls. When I resize the window I would like to resize the content as well, meaning the controls should take more space and also the text should be bigger, images, icons, and so forth.*

Example, simplified but showing the idea -- I have two buttons around the slider, like:

> [-] ------||-- [+]

Buttons are scaled up as expected, the slider knob as well, but the ruler of the slider is not visible at all. While writing this code in Visual Studio it is also apparent that scaling went wrong, because focus-box drawn around slider is way too small.

```xml
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Viewbox DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Button Padding="0">-</Button>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Button Padding="0">+</Button>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox  DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Slider VerticalAlignment="Center"></Slider>
        </Viewbox>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Add code example

Answer (score 2):

Set `Stretch` property to `Fill` and set the `Width` of the `Slider`. It will effect the width of the knob.

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Viewbox DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Button Padding="0">-</Button>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Button Padding="0">+</Button>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Slider Width="100"></Slider>
        </Viewbox>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work as expected. The purpose of this scaling is to scale entire content up to the size of the window, while window is resized by the user. If I set the fixed value for slider it is only a good match of given size of the window. In any other case it is incorrectly scaled (down or up). Also setting the width have strange result -- the sizes of knob and ruler behave like opposites. For example with width set to 20 I have huge knob and short ruler, with width 200 I have longer ruler, but tiny knob.